# Build with @angular/cli from another folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm writing a script that will build my app. This script is outside of my app folder. I can't figure out how to build with `@angular/cli` from another folder.

Let say the structure is `applications/my-app/.angular-cli.json`. How can I build the app from `applications/.`? Is there a way to tell `@angular/cli` to look in the `./my-app` folder while building with `ng build`?

Comment: What are you using to create the build script?

Comment: Take a look at [nrwl/nx](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) if you're interested in multiapp setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually not. It looks up from the working directory up to the first `node_modules` it finds.

See [**github**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5120)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can temporary change the working directory in the script. Take a look a the [`pushd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx) and [`popd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490969.aspx) commands.